# Не подгружается контент в Yii2. Не срабатывает роутинг

Tags: yii2, apache, веб-сервер

Вот такая у меня проблема... Сделал сайт на `Yii2`. Развернул на удаленном хостинге(все редиректы были заранее сделаны на своем локальном сервере), поменял только конфиг для базы данных и все как надо работает.
 Отдал заказчику. Он у себя с нуля собрал сервер, поставил пакеты и в результате шапка сайта, футер, нав. меню загружаются (т.е. база данных подключена и работает), а та часть которая `$content`,- нет (срабатывает стандартный site/error).
 Получается, что не срабатывает роутинг? Возможно ли, что не та версия apache?
Может быть еще какие-то пакеты поставить нужно? Что это может быть?

Вот Работающий сайт http://koscomtest.ru/
Вот у заказчика http://kos-com.ru/

Comment: http://koscomtest.ru/  Server: nginx-reuseport/1.13.4, 
http://kos-com.ru/ Server: Apache/2.4.18
Приложите .htaccess к вашему вопросу